# Varios campos de búsqueda en tabla PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-tabla

Necesito añadir a algunas tablas, más de un campo de búsqueda, para que puedan buscar por (número de pedido, referencia, codigo de cliente..)

Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento, y solo consigo hacer funcionar cuando tengo un  si añado más, deja de funcionar.

Campos de búsqueda y tabla:

```
      <form method="POST" action="" onSubmit="return validarForm(this)"> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar Nº de pedido" name="palabra">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Buscar Referencia" name="referencia">   
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar">     
      </form>

        <?php

        require('conexion.php');

        $arrMensaje=array();

        if ($mysqli){

            $buscar='%'.$_POST["palabra"].'%';
            $referencia='%'.$_POST["referencia"].'%';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE ordern LIKE ? OR referencia LIKE ?";

            $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

            if ($stmt) {

                $stmt->bind_param("i", $buscar, $referencia);
                $stmt->execute();

                $arrResultado=get_pedidos($stmt);

            if ($arrResultado){
                    $strHTML='<table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <th >Pedido</th>
                                        <th >Fecha</th>
                                        <th >Almacen</th>
                                        <th >Cliente</th>
                                        <th >Referencia</th>
                                        <th >Estado</th>                            
                                     </thead>
                                     <tbody>';

                    foreach ($arrResultado as $row)
                    {
                        $strHTML.='<tr>';
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["ordern"]."</td>";
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["fecha"]."</td>";
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["almacen"]."</td>";
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["id"]."</td>";
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["referencia"]."</td>";  
                        $strHTML.='<td>'.$row["estado"]."</td>";                      
                        $strHTML.='</tr>';

                    }

                    $strHTML.='</tbody>';
                    $strHTML.='</table>';

                    echo $strHTML;
            }else{
                $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"No se cumplieron los criterios de búsqueda");
            }

                $stmt->close();

            }else{

                $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"Hubo un fallo en la consulta: ".$mysqli->error);

            }

            $mysqli->close();


        }else{

            $arrMensaje=array("error"=>"La conexión es nula: ".$mysqli->error);
        }

        if ($arrMensaje){
            echo $arrMensaje["error"];
        }

        function get_pedidos( $Statement ) {
            $RESULT = array();
            $Statement->store_result();
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
                $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
                $PARAMS = array();
                while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
                    $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
                }
                call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
                $Statement->fetch();
            }
            return $RESULT;
        }
        ?>
```

Script para verificar si el campo está vacio (solo el primer campo):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarForm(formulario) 
    {
        if(formulario.palabra.value.length==0) 
        { //¿Tiene 0 caracteres?
            formulario.palabra.focus();  // Damos el foco al control
            alert('Debes rellenar este campo'); //Mostramos el mensaje
            return false; 
         } //devolvemos el foco  
         return true; //Si ha llegado hasta aquí, es que todo es correcto 
     }   
</script>
```

Comment: Que es exactamente que te deja de funcionar?, podrías poner la consulta que intentas hacer al añadir mas campos a la búsqueda?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Partamos de la base que una consulta del tipo

```
SELECT * FROM nombres WHERE nombre like '%%'
```

O sea `LIKE '%%'` siempre se cumple.

Ahora bien, tú puedes estar enviando uno o dos parámetros: `palabra` y/o `referencia`. Entonces debieras declarar tus variables como:

```
$buscar=isset($_POST["palabra"])? '%'.$_POST["palabra"].'%' : '%%';
$referencia=isset($_POST["referencia"])? '%'.$_POST["referencia"].'%' : '%%';
```

Esto es: si no viene la variable por post, usas una cadena vacía.

Luego al hacer bind de los parámetros, le dices que son dos strings:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $buscar, $referencia);
```

De ahí en adelante no tengo idea qué hará `get_pedidos($stmt);` pero supongo que sabes lo que estás haciendo.

Edit: creo que te estás sobrecomplicando en el método `get_pedidos`. Si sabes de antemano los campos que quieres, aplica `bind_result`.Yo haría algo como:

```
$sql = "SELECT ordern, fecha, almacen, id, referencia, estado FROM pedidos WHERE ordern LIKE ? OR referencia LIKE ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

// Ojo con el primer parámetro, que es "ss"
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $buscar, $referencia);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $strHTML = '<table>
        <thead>
            <th >Pedido</th>
            <th >Fecha</th>
            <th >Almacen</th>
            <th >Cliente</th>
            <th >Referencia</th>
            <th >Estado</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

    $stmt->bind_result($ordern,$fecha,$almacen,$id,$referencia,$estado);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $strHTML .= '<tr>';
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $ordern . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $fecha . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $almacen . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $id . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $referencia . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '<td>' . $estado . "</td>";
            $strHTML .= '</tr>';
    }

    $strHTML .= '</tbody>';
    $strHTML .= '</table>';

    echo $strHTML;       

}
```

Comment: No consigo que funcione, y la verdad que no entiendo el porque no me resulta, he probado varios métodos, y ninguno me saca .. simplemente es añadir varios campos de busqueda para buscar en la tabla.. De esta forma no me funciona :/

Comment: Le añadí una sugerencia para reemplazar el uso de `get_pedidos` que realmente es muy críptico

Comment: que interesante que se vote en contra una respuesta aceptada. Cada día una mejor comunidad.